# 'None' gradients in pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, mixture-model

I am trying to implement a simple MDN that predicts the parameters of a distribution over a target variable instead of a point value, and then assigns probabilities to discrete bins of the point value. Narrowing down the issue, the code from which the 'None' springs is:

```
import torch

# params
tte_bins = np.linspace(
    start=0, 
    stop=399, 
    num=400, 
    dtype='float32'
).reshape(1, 1, -1)
bins = torch.tensor(tte_bins, dtype=torch.float32)
x_train = np.random.randn(1, 1024, 3)
y_labels = np.random.randint(low=0, high=399, size=(1, 1024))
y_train = np.eye(400)[y_labels]

# data
in_train = torch.tensor(x_train[0:1, :, :], dtype=torch.float)
in_train = (in_train - torch.mean(in_train)) / torch.std(in_train)
out_train = torch.tensor(y_train[0:1, :, :], dtype=torch.float)

# model
linear = torch.nn.Linear(in_features=3, out_features=2)
lin = linear(in_train)
preds = torch.exp(lin)

# intermediate values
alpha = torch.clamp(preds[0:1, :, 0:1], 0, 500)
beta = torch.clamp(preds[0:1, :, 1:2], 0, 100)

# probs
p1 = torch.exp(-torch.pow(bins / alpha, beta))
p2 = torch.exp(-torch.pow((bins + 1.0) / alpha, beta))
probs = p1 - p2

# loss
loss = torch.mean(torch.pow(out_train - probs, 2))

# gradients
loss.backward()
for p in linear.parameters():
    print(p.grad, 'gradient')
```

in_train has shape: [1, 1024, 3], out_train has shape: [1, 1024, 400], bins has shape: [1, 1, 400]. All the broadcasting etc.. appears find, the resulting matrices (like alpha/beta/loss) are the right shape and have the right values - there's simply no gradients

edit: added `loss.backward()` and `x_train/y_train`, now I have `nans`

Comment: Can you add information about your input `x_train` and `y_train`?

Comment: added example data, nans appear to come from elsewhere

Comment: you never use `y_labels` and `test`is not defined. your code should always be minimal and reproducible.

Comment: The gradients explode when you compute `p1` and `p2`. Using `preds.sum().backward()` still produces valid gradients. I do not know what you are trying to compute with your model. However, when dcomputing the derivative of `p1`with respect to `alpha` for example, you get a multiplicative factor of `bins**(beta)`which will probably be very large.

Comment: noted, fixed that test/y_labels

Comment: As I said, I don't know about your model, but at least one problem is, that when clamping `alpha`, alpha is zero sometimes. In the derivative you divide by `alpha` giving you `nan`s.

Comment: Changed clamp to epsilon, and you are right - my gradients for alpha are huge. I'll have to think about how to rewrite this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply forgot to compute the gradients. While you calculate the loss, you never tell `pytorch` with respect to which function it should calculate the gradients.

Simply adding

```
loss.backward()
```

to your code should fix the problem.

Additionally, in your code some intermediate results like `alpha` are sometimes zero but are in a denominator when computing the gradient. This will lead to the `nan` results you observed.

Comment: Added, except now I get all nans as the gradient output